# Javascript - avoid multiple array.filters being called

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a piece of code that looks like:

```
const desktop = platform.filter(el => el == "desktop").length;
const mobile = platform.filter(el => el == "mobile").length;
const android = platform.filter(el => el == "android").length;
```

and so on..

Basically I have an array that contains multiple entries of those strings and I want to collect the length of each property in a variable. The above works but I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to avoid filter through the array multiple times?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a single reduce to count the number of appearances of the items:

```js
const platform = ['desktop', 'other', 'mobile', '', 'other', 'android', 'android'];

const { desktop, mobile, android } = platform.reduce((r, el) => {
  if (el in r) r[el]++;

  return r;
}, { desktop: 0, mobile: 0, android: 0 });

console.log({ desktop, mobile, android });
```

Answer (score 0):

While it would not avoid the multiple iterations, you could write an equivalent more cleanly:

```
const desktop = platform .includes ("desktop")
const mobile =  platform .includes ("mobile")
const android = platform .includes ("android")
```

But if the multiple iterations are a real problem, Ori Drori's technique should cover it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` and build one generic object.

```js
const platforms = ['desktop', 'android', 'desktop', 'android', 'mobile'];
const len = platforms.reduce(
  (acc, item) =>
    Object.assign(acc, { [item]: item in acc ? acc[item] + 1 : 1 }),
  {}
);

console.log(len['desktop'], len.mobile)
```